# Can Execute of a ICommand while a Context menu open

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, icommand, canexecute

A Control has its `ContextMenu` and its `MenuItem` is bound to an `ICommand`. ICommand's Can Execute has some code to enable and disable the `MenuItem`. This hits while loading and checks for Can Execute but it can hit while open the `ContexMenu` and it need to be hit(Checks) for each time while opening the `ContextMenu`.

```
<Border>
    <Border.ContextMenu> 
       <ContextMenu> 
           <MenuItem Command="{Binding SaveCommand, Source={StaticResource vm}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Header="Menu1" />
       </ContextMenu> 
    </Border.ContextMenu>
</Border>
```

How could be done this. Any idea?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: Pls check the above code

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger the event ICommand.CanExecuteChanged() from ViewModel which shall cause the Control to invoke CanExecute from ViewModel.

Comment: This might be work but not in my case.. any generic way to achieve this?

Comment: There is some information missing here: when do you call the CanExecuteChanged? @Sankarann wants it to be evaluated when the contextmenu opens (and so do I).